# How does python apply filters to specific columns?

Tags: python, numpy, data-science

The NumPy array data has a shape of (1000, ). More specifically, look at the code below:

```
data = np.genfromtext("data.csv", delimiter=",", skip_header=1, names=("Score", "GPA", "Research"))
```

I want to find out how many students have research experience. I apply this filter(The score column is a binary column):

```
data[data["Research"] == 1]
```

This returns a new array containing the data of all students with research experience.
I don't understand how Python applies the boolean mask to only the "Score" column. It should apply the mask to the entire array; what happens if there exists more than one binary column?

I try to understand the code by separating a new variable for the mask and then passing the mask to the data; the results are the same.

Comment: I'd suggest you use pandas for such king of data, it's more appropriate

Comment: `data["Research"]` is a view into your `data` array, which extracts the `.research` field of your structured data type - https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#accessing-individual-fields. So the result of `data["Research"] == 1` is a single-column boolean array, which is interpreted as a sequence of row indexes when evaluating `data[data["Research"] == 1]`

Comment: what is `data.dtype`? It looks like you have a 1d `structured array`.  The array has `fields`, not olumns.  If so, you need to read more about this in `numpy` docs.

Comment: without `names` in `genfrontxt`,  `data` would be a 2d array with shape (1000,3).  Then `data[:, 2]` will be the last column.

Comment: @slothrop but what if there exist multiple binary columns in the data matrix? I still don't understand how python applies the array to only the research field

Comment: @CuriousBoy it uses only the research field in determining which rows (because your criterion is specifically `data['Research'] == 1`. Then the result contains all fields for those rows. If you had another binary field in your structure (let's call it `foo`) then  `data[data['Research'] == 1]` would give different results to `data[data['foo'] == 1]` - i.e. different rows of the array would be selected.

Comment: Note, when you say "...how python applies..." - we're looking specifically at **numpy** behaviour here. numpy makes heavy use of operator overriding so that subscripting with `[ ... ]` behaves quite differently from plain Python data structures.